# How to filter data based using date column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

How to fetch data from 3 tables with max date

```
select 
    c.model_key, v.id, v.category_Id, v.Text1, v.Numeric1,
    c.Name, fx.Currency_code, fx.Rate, fx.effective_dt 
from 
    aps.v_m_fxrates fx 
join 
    aps.t_m_value v on fx.Currency_code = v.Text1 
join 
    aps.t_m_category c on v.Category_Id = c.Id 
where 
    c.Name = 'FXRates' 
    and c.Model_Key = 25 
    and v.Text1 = fx.Currency_code 
    and fx.version = 2
```

Using the above query I get results, but the results appearing for all the `effective_dt`. Instead of this, I need to pick only the records with latest `effective_dt`. In the below image, there is 2 records with AED in which the one with latest date is 1999-03-31 which must be returned. After this I do not know how to proceed and filter the result further to achieve the output.

I also tried this

```
select 
    c.model_key, v.id, v.category_Id, v.Numeric1,
    c.Name, fx.Currency_code, fx.Rate, fx.effective_dt 
from 
    aps.v_m_fxrates fx 
join 
    aps.t_m_value v on fx.Currency_code = v.Text1 
join 
    aps.t_m_category c on v.Category_Id = c.Id 
where 
    c.Name = 'FXRates' 
    and c.Model_Key = 25 
    and v.Text1 = fx.Currency_code 
    and fx.version = 2 
    and fx.effective_dt in (select MAX(effective_dt) 
                            from aps.v_m_fxrates)
```

but nothing is being returned.

Actual output:

[image: Actual Outcome]

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ***row_number()*** function in a subquery like this:

```
select 
     c.model_key, v.id, v.category_Id, v.Text1, v.Numeric1,
     c.Name, fx.Currency_code, fx.Rate, fx.effective_dt 
from (
    select
         Currency_code,Rate,effective_dt
        ,SeqNo = row_number() over (partition by Currency_code order by effective_dt desc)
    from aps.v_m_fxrates 
    where version = 2
) fx 
join 
    aps.t_m_value v on fx.Currency_code = v.Text1 
join 
    aps.t_m_category c on v.Category_Id = c.Id 
where c.Name = 'FXRates' 
  and c.Model_Key = 25 
  and v.Text1 = fx.Currency_code 
  and fx.SeqNo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use operator **TOP 1** and corresponding **ORDER BY**

For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 C.model_key,
             V.id,
             ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY FX.effective_dt DESC
```

Another option that you have is using aggregate function and correlation in where clause.

```
select C.model_key,
       V.id,
       V.category_Id, 
       V.Text1,
       V.Numeric1,
       C.Name, 
       FX.Currency_code,
       FX.Rate,
       FX.effective_dt 
FROM aps.v_m_fxrates AS FX
    JOIN aps.t_m_value AS V on FX.Currency_code = V.Text1 
    JOIN aps.t_m_category AS C on V.Category_Id = C.Id 
WHERE C.Name = 'FXRates' 
          AND C.Model_Key = 25
          AND FX.version = 2
          AND FX.effective_dt = 
                (SELECT MAX(effective_dt) FROM aps.v_m_fxrates AS FX2
                 WHERE FX2.currency_code = FX.currency_code)
```

Comment: your second option seems to be correct .my task requires something related to correlated subquery .but this dint work for me.the whole result of outer query must go into inner query  to fetch the required result. but this inner query will compare only single record right?

Comment: In the inner query you are selecting max effective_dt for currency code from outer query. So, records with max effective_dt for each currency code will go to result table. I think your problem may be in additional join operators that could filter rows. So try to add two table joins to inner query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    c.model_key, v.id,v.category_Id, v.Numeric1,
    c.Name, fx.Currency_code, fx.Rate, fx.effective_dt 
from 
    aps.v_m_fxrates fx 
join 
    aps.t_m_value v on fx.Currency_code = v.Text1 
join 
   aps.t_m_category c on v.Category_Id = c.Id 
where 
   c.Name = 'FXRates' 
   and c.Model_Key = 25 
   and v.Text1 = fx.Currency_code 
   and fx.version = 2 
   and fx.effective_dt = (select MAX(effective_dt) from aps.v_m_fxrates)
```

Try this; you used `fx.effective_dt in`, but instead you have to use `=` because you want maximum date record. After using `=` it will return only one row.